# use helper function to set the <title> of magento admin menu item

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, xml, helper

I'm using magento 1.9.1.
I want to add dynamic value beside admin menu items to represent the state. for example: under catalog, I want to add number representing the unapproved products beside manage products.
so my question is: can I use a function defined in the helper of my module in the adminhtml.xml file within the  node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how menu title is rendered you should look at `_getHelperValue()` method inside `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` class.

```
protected function _getHelperValue(Varien_Simplexml_Element $child)
{
    $helperName         = 'adminhtml';
    $titleNodeName      = 'title';
    $childAttributes    = $child->attributes();
    if (isset($childAttributes['module'])) {
        $helperName     = (string)$childAttributes['module'];
    }

    return Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$child->$titleNodeName);
}
```

First it checks if your menu item has `module` property and then uses that to translate text in `<title>` node by calling `__()` method. If module property is not set, it will use `adminhtml` helper.

So I guess you can either set `module` property on your menu xml and do something funky with `__()` method in your helper, which seems kinda odd btw, or rewrite admin menu block and add your custom logic.

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestions. just to put you in the image, what I/m trying to achieve here is helping the admin by giving him info in the menu. for example tell him that you have 15 unapproved products so that he open the page and start approving them. another example, is under sales tell him that he has 10 new orders sothat he can start processing them, instead of keep vising the pages to check if there are any new orders or products.
so I thought of this and since I saw the helper used within <url> node to get the url dynamically I wondered if I can do the same with the title